# Keep Likes after moving URL

Tags: facebook, url, migration, facebook-like

After moving URLs on my website, I lost all likes that I had earned.

I tried to put old urls on the href iframe, it works half because it shows number of likes but when I click to "Like", it restarts from 0 (I think it's because it greps the new canonical url).

Is there a way to get back likes on my new url?

Ex : 
Old URLs : http://www.example.org/categories/manufacturers/products-p-1488.html (with canonical)
New URLs : http://www.example.org/products-p-1488.html (with canonical)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I 301 redirect a page in the open graph and retain facebook like information?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7197919/how-can-i-301-redirect-a-page-in-the-open-graph-and-retain-facebook-like-informa)

Comment: possible duplicate of [URL change, retaining facebook likes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691590/url-change-retaining-facebook-likes)